# Angular PinCode Modal Authetication

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to create a Pincode based authentication in Angular as below design:

[image]

Can someone guide me? I've already looked into some libraries but it doesn't fulfill my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Great idea! I can totally see myself needing this in the future as well. Angular projects on the web don't seem to have such a component laying around. Code wise it looks quite straight forward to do though. Mostly HTML and CSS.

If you were to make one here's some tips.

1. Make it as an component so it's reusable. Allow to pass on params (order name, order nr etc). Here is something to get you started and a good example how to obfuscate the pin if necessary: https://morioh.com/p/6a5fda70f894
2. Call the component out as a dialog modal (this gives you backdrop, animations and tends to prevent other style errors when dealing with absolute positioning and overlays) https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview